# Typesetting the source code documentation for xcolor

Tags: compiling, dtx

I want to get the source code documentation for the [`xcolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package. For this, I removed `\OnlyDescription` from `xcolor.dtx` (line 111) and ran

```
pdflatex xcolor.dtx
pdflatex xcolor.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist xcolor.idx
pdflatex xcolor.dtx
pdflatex xcolor.dtx
```

As a result I have a documentation, but the section "The Implementation" is missing, even though there is no `\OnlyDescription` anymore.

How do I get the complete documentation, including the part with the source code?

Comment: If I remove `\OnlyDescription` (or replace it by `\AlsoImplementation`, just to be sure) I get an error about differing checksum. Then if I replace `\CheckSum{4864}` by the reported `4884` it works...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Hmm, I don't get any checksum errors and `\AlsoImplementation` does not help either. Weird..

Comment: Just in case that matters: I'm on Windows with MiKTeX.

Comment: The distribution shouldn't matter... It's been long since `xcolor` was updated (I have `2016/05/11 v2.12`), so they should be equal. Try removing `\StopEventually`....

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That did it! Why, though..?

Comment: `\OnlyDescription` and `\AlsoImplementation` just change the definition of `\StopEventually`. `\OnlyDescription` makes `\StopEventually` do an `\endinput` and  `\AlsoImplementation` makes it a no-op (roughly speaking). Without a `\StopEventually`, the other two macros are useless.